# NodeJS/MongoDB - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am quite new to NodeJS and I tried looking at the accepted answers here, did some digging but couldn't find any specific reason still what's happening in my particular example below. Any ideas, what can be wrong ? I only know there is something to do with the res.

I also suspect that there might be an interfere beetween the way I `get` the `html file` and the way I get the `products` from the `db`?

My server.js:

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
server = http.createServer(app)
var formidable = require('express-formidable');
app.use(formidable());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
global.db = null
var sDatabasePath = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/webshop'
global.mongoId = require('mongodb').ObjectID

/**************************************************/

var user = require(path.join(__dirname + '/user.js'))

/**************************************************/


app.get('/shopaholic', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/shopaholic.html')) })

mongo.connect(sDatabasePath, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 003 -> Cannot connect to the database')
        return false
    }
    global.db = db
    console.log('OK 002 -> Connected to the database')
    return true
})


/**************************************************/

app.post('/save-user', (req, res) => {
    user.saveUser(req.fields, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(jResult)
            return res.send('ERROR')
        }
        console.log(jResult)
        return res.send('OK')

    })
})

/**************************************************/

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    user.getProducts((err, ajUsers) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('ERROR')
        }
        console.log(ajUsers)
        return res.send(ajUsers)

    })
})
app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 001 -> Cannot listen to port 3000')
        return false
    }
    console.log('OK 000 -> Server listening to port 3000')
})
```

My user.js:

```
var user = {}

/**************************************************/


user.getProducts = (fCallback) => {
    // get the data from the collection users
    global.db.collection('products').find().toArray((err, ajUsers) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> user.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)
        }
        console.log("ajUsers", ajUsers);
        return fCallback(false, ajUsers)
    })
}

/**************************************************/

user.saveUser = (jUserData, fcallback) => {
    var jUser = { "userName": jUserData.txtEmailorPhoneNumber, "firstName": jUserData.txtName, "lastName": jUserData.txtLastName, "password": jUserData.txtPassword, "image": jUserData.imgPath }
    global.db.collection('users').insertOne(jUser, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> user.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)

        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js -> saved -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        return fcallback(false, jOk)
    })
}


/**************************************************/

module.exports = user
```

JAVACRIPT on the front-end (shopaholic.html) :

```
btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", signupUser);

        function signupUser() {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    var ajUserDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    //console.log( "Response:" + ajUserDataFromServer );

                    if (ajUserDataFromServer.status == "ok") {

                        //console.log( "SIGNUP SUCCESFULL" );
                        pageLogin.style.display = "flex";
                        lblLoginErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                        var sSignupSeuccesMessage = "Account succesfully created - Signup please";
                        var sSignupSeuccesMessage = sSignupSeuccesMessage.fontcolor("#549839");
                        lblLoginErrorMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sSignupSeuccesMessage);

                    } else {

                        //console.log( "SIGNUP FAIL - TRY AGAIN" );
                        pageViewProducts.style.display = "none";
                        pageSignup.style.display = "flex";
                        lblSignupErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                        var sSignupErrorMessage = "Signup Failed - Try again";
                        lblSignupErrorMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sSignupErrorMessage);

                    }
                }
            }

            request.open("POST", "/save-user", true);
            var jFrmSignup = new FormData(frmSignup);
            request.send(jFrmSignup);
        }

 function getajProductData() {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    ajProductDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    //console.log( "Response:" + ajProductDataFromServer );

                    if (sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "admin") {
                        //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE EDITABLE" );
                        showProductAdmin();

                    } else if (sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "user") {
                        //console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE AVAILABLE FOR USER" );
                        showProduct();

                    } else {
                        //console.log( "PRODUCTS AVAILABLE FOR PUBLIC" );
                        showProduct();
                    }

                }
            }

            request.open("GET", "/products", true);
            request.send();

        }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code you've posted.

Comment: probably cause you don´t have the front-end : shopaholic.html. I forgot to mention that the error occurs when I load the page on localhost. I have added now the javascript I use on the front-end.